# Warning: require_once(PLUSPEOPLE/autoload.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php

I am trying to install a money transfer API called "pesapi"
[This is how the error is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TWrv.jpg).

```
<?php
namespace Pluspeople\Pesapi;
set_include_path("..local_include:../include:" . get_include_path()); 
require_once("PLUSPEOPLE/autoload.php");
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: does the directory exist and PHP installation and server got access to it? the user for the PHP, check it access to it too...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are running it on windows?

Replace the `:` with `PATH_SEPARATOR` in your `set_include_path`. Like this:

```
set_include_path("../local_include" . PATH_SEPARATOR . "../include" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

The path separator for windows is `;` and not `:`

Comment: You are welcome. You may accept the answer if it solved your issue.